# Are there some ways to change settings of Qt Creator syntax highlighting?

Tags: c++, qt, syntax, qt-creator

I'm using Qt Creator 4.6.2 based on Qt 5.11.1 in Ubuntu 18.10 to C++ programming with `CONFIG += console c++17` key in `.pro` file and I got problem with following code:

```
std::for_each(attributes.begin(), attributes.end(), [&,i{0}](auto it) mutable {compressed.col_id[i] = it.first; i++;});
```

Qt Creator underlines this code in red and says "expected token ';' got '{'"  but compiler runs this code without problems.
Also when I tried to run this code:

```
int i = 0;
std::for_each(attributes.begin(), attributes.end(), [&](auto it) mutable {compressed.col_id[i] = it.first; i++;});
```

Qt Creator not underlined it.

I think it could be some problems with parsing in IDE so how I can deal with it?

Comment: Side note: I think `std::transform` does what you want better than `std::for_each` paired with additional counter. Good question nonetheless

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use the ClangCodeModel for C++. It might be experimental in your version but I´ve used it there as well. Might be slow though.

[image: Clang Code Model]

Answer (score 0):

Clang Code Model for C++ was upgraded to libclang 6.0 and switched on by default in QtCreator 4.7.0, so anyone with 4.7.0 or higher shouldn't have this problem.

I find that the OPs code doesn't compile for a different reason... `it.first` should be just `it`.

But after changing that, the code compiles fine with:

```
CONFIG += c++14
```

or with

```
CONFIG += c++1z
```

without any complaints from the syntax highlighter